# i want display the name of registered user on next page

Tags: php

i want to show the name of user who recently registered on my site ,the username is to be displayed on next linked page ,i am using the following code but it is only displaying welcome

```
<?php
 echo "<h3>Welcome&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$_SESSION['fullname']."</h3>";

 ?>
```

Comment: `session_start();` Maybe? Before you use the `$_SESSION` variable

Comment: Did you start the session and how is it being defined? Even by adding `session_start();` won't do much good without it being defined elsewhere.

Comment: yes i have placed that on top of every page

Comment: @arman Then show us where you assign the value to `$_SESSION['fullname']`

Comment: `<?php session_start(); $_SESSION['fullname'] = "Joe"; echo $_SESSION['fullname'];` there, now it's defined.

Comment: please do a  var_dump($_SESSION)

Comment: let we do it again and then let you know

Comment: i have place session_start() in php tags ?

Comment: @arman What do you think `session_start();` is? HTML code?

Answer (score 0):

At login page start session

```
session_start();
```

then assign value to this session like

```
$_SESSION['fullname'] = $_REQUEST['fullname'];
```

Then on next page also start session

```
 session_start();
```

then use your code

```
echo "<h3>Welcome&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$_SESSION['fullname']."</h3>";
```

Comment: i have place session_start() in php tags ?

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: fullname in C:\wamp\www\interview\index.php on line 22  this is the page where i want to display the user name

Comment: @session_start(); i have placed this on every page in php tags

Comment: $_SESSION['fullname'] = $_REQUEST['fullname']; where in login page i have to place this code i am placing it next to session start line

Comment: i am not able to paste my code here it is showing error

Answer (score 0):

on first page that is registration page and also on login page
at the top on very first line paste the following line of code

```
session_start();
```

after successful registration or login assign some value to session variable

```
$_SESSION['fullname']=$_POST['fullname'];//this may be getched from DB or form post
```

now you will be able to get this `$_SESSION['fullname']` an any page but remember, session variables are only available if you have started session at top of page. means on any page you want to display user fullname just write it as below.

```
//at first line of page
session_start();
//your html/js/css code

//where ever you want to display fullname write it as below
echo "Welcome ".$_SESSION['fullname']."!";
//your more html/js/css code
```

hope this will help you

**EDITED**
write these 2 lines at top of next page

```
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);
```

it will display you all session variables. this way you can start debugging your session variables

Comment: i have place session_start() in php tags ?

Comment: see edited portion of my answer, and if possible post your code

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this:-**

1) Root PHP file in add this.

```
if (substr_count($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'], 'gzip'))
{
        ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
}
else
{
        ob_start();
}
session_set_cookie_params(0);
session_start();

//set the level of error reporting
//error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED);
error_reporting(0);
```

2) other page in "SESSION" Add.

```
$_SESSION['fullname'] = "Fullname";
```

3) You can check other page "SESSION"

```
echo $_SESSION['fullname'];
```